# "Most important const" with conditional expression?

Tags: c++, conditional-operator

Consider the following code:

```
int foo(MyClass const* aPtr = 0) {
    MyClass const& a = aPtr ? *aPtr : MyClass(); // Either bind to *aPtr, or to a default-constructed MyClass
    ...
    return a.bar();
}
```

The ["most important const"](http://herbsutter.com/2008/01/01/gotw-88-a-candidate-for-the-most-important-const/) is, hopefully, being used here. The aim is to allow for a null `aPtr` to be passed in (BTW, yes, it must be a pointer argument), in which case a temporary `MyClass` object would be default-constructed, and its lifetime extended by a const reference binding to it. Whereas, if `aPtr` was not null, the reference would bind to its pointed-to object without any (expensive) copy construction happening.

The questions two are:

1. If `aPtr == 0`, is `a` guaranteed to refer to a valid `MyClass` object until the end of the function?
2. If `aPtr != 0`, will `a` bind to it, rather than to some other `MyClass`?

Based on testing, the answer to 1 is almost certainly "yes". #2 I'm not so sure about, though (copy elision and such)... it seems possible that the conditional expression would end up copy-constructing a temporary `MyClass` from `*aPtr`, and extending the life of *that* temporary.

Comment: (1) The poor `aPtr == 0` ends the lifetime of `a` at the first `;`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your conditional expression is a prvalue (because one of its operands is). If the first alternative of the conditional operator is selected, it is converted to a temporary (which incurs a copy). That temporary is bound to the reference, and the usual life-time extension applies.

The relevant standardese [expr.cond]:

> If the operands have class type, the result is a prvalue temporary of the result type, which is copy-initialized from either the second operand or the third operand depending on the value of the first operand.

Comment: And the workaround: `static MyClass default; a = *(aptr ? aptr : &default);`

Comment: @MarkRansom Ah, I like that. And if default construction/destruction are expensive, then it's potentially more efficient than the original approach would have been anyway.

Comment: ... and the 'usual life-time extension' ends at the semicolon.

Comment: @DieterLücking No it doesn't, see my answer.

Answer (score 3):

To the first, yes `a` is guaranteed to refer to a valid `MyClass` object. This comes directly from [class.temporary]/4-5:

> There are two contexts in which temporaries are destroyed at a different point than the end of the fullexpression. The first context is when a default constructor is called [...]
>
> The second context is when a reference is bound to a temporary. The temporary to which the reference is
>   bound or the temporary that is the complete object of a subobject to which the reference is bound **persists
>   for the lifetime of the reference** except:
>
> - A temporary bound to a reference member in a constructor’s *ctor-initializer* [...]
> - A temporary bound to a reference parameter in a function call [...]
> - The lifetime of a temporary bound to the returned value in a function return statement [...]
> - A temporary bound to a reference in a *new-initializer* [...]

None of those exceptions apply.

If `aPtr` is a valid pointer, then a copy is made because the type of `aPtr ? *aPtr : MyClass{}` is just `MyClass`. That temporary gets bound to `a`, and *its* lifetime also persists for the same reason.

Answer (score 1):

About 1) See kerek's answer above

About 2) The standard says about conditional operator:

> **5.16/4:** If the second and third operands are glvalues of the **same value category** and have the **same type**, the result is of that type and value category (...).
>
> **5.16/5:** Otherwise, the result is a prvalue. (...)

According to the taxonomy of lvalues and rvalues in **3.10/1**, `*aPtr` is an lvalue ,  `MyClass()` is an prvalue .  Hence the result should be a prvalue so that the reference should refer to this temporary (potentially a copy constructed temp).

**Edit:** Here an **[online demo](http://ideone.com/Fv5NZT)**,  which shows that the const reference refers to a temporary and not to the original object pointed to by aPtr.

Comment: 1) `MyClass()` is a prvalue. 2) "Value category" is one of lvalue, xvalue and prvalue.

Comment: @T.C. if a prvalue can't be on the left site of an assignment, why does [this](http://ideone.com/ebiMfJ) compile successfully ?  i'd just like to be sure because I'm always hesitant about xvalues.

Comment: Who said that prvalues can't be on the lhs of an assignment? Only the built-in assignment operator requires a modifiable lvalue as its left operand.